# Check Consecutive 13 digits in java

Tags: java

Hi All I'm using the following function to check the Consecutive digits in java

The issue im facing here is it works for the first Consecutive digits only

**For example** it work for **123456789123456XXXX** 
but want this to work Consecutive any where
**XXXX123456789123456** or **XX123456789123456XX**

**Update**

Now if i found 13 Consecutive digits then i need to pass all Consecutive digits to the mask function

and my result should be 
something like this

for input **123456789123456XXXX** result should be **123456%%%%%3456XXXX**

for input **XXXX123456789123456** result should be **XX123456%%%%%3456XX**

Please help me to solve this

**My Code**

```
public void checkPosCardNoAndMask(String cardNo) {
    String maskNumber = "";
    String starValue = "";
    boolean isConsecutive = false;
    int checkConsecutive = 0;
    for (int i = 0, len = cardNo.length(); i < len; i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(cardNo.charAt(i))) {
            maskNumber = maskNumber + cardNo.charAt(i);
        } else {
            if (checkConsecutive >= 13)
                isConsecutive = true;
            else
                break;
            starValue = starValue + cardNo.charAt(i);
        }
        checkConsecutive++;
    }
    if (isConsecutive)
    {
     cardNo = maskCCNumber(maskNumber) + starValue;
     System.out.printIn("Consecutive found!!:"+cardNo);
    }
    else
    {
     System.out.printIn("Consecutive not found!!:"+cardNo);
    }

}
```

**Masking logic**

```
public String maskCCNumber(String ccNo)
    {
        String maskCCNo = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < ccNo.length(); i++)
        {
            if (i > 5 && i < ccNo.length() - 4)
            {
                maskCCNo = maskCCNo + '%';
            }
            else
            {
                maskCCNo = maskCCNo + ccNo.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        return maskCCNo;
    }
```

Comment: So sathish you want to check whether your string contain 13 consecutive number i.e. 123456789123456 or thr may b some other strings ?

Comment: @Youngistan yes need to check 13 consecutive numbers, but the numbers are dynamic

Comment: what's the next number for 9? was it 0 or 1? --nevermind, I think I understand the term consecutive wrongly.

Comment: XX123456789123456XX  , ab123456789123456XX ,76123456789123456XX
is this all format are valid or not? XX mean any charactor ,number or conclusive numbers?

Comment: @madhawa111111 all for are valid

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic ? So number 111213141516.. which also be treated as consecutive ?

Comment: @Youngistan can you help me to my updated question.. yes you are right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `regex` you can do this way:

```
  String str = "XX123456789123456XX";
    if (str.matches(".*\\d{13}.*")) {
        System.out.println(true);
        Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(str);
        matcher.find();
        String masked = maskCCNumber(matcher.group());//send 123456789123456 and returns 123456%%%%%3456
        String finalString=str.replaceAll("\\d+", masked);// replace all digits with 123456%%%%%3456
        System.out.println(finalString);

    }
```

Output:

```
true 
XX123456%%%%%3456XX
```

Comment: @Sathish Do you want to extract these 13 digits from the string?

Comment: if 13 Consecutive digits found i need to take all Consecutive digits and mask and concat beck to normal for input XXXX123456789123456 result should be XX123456%%%%%3456XX

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues:

- You're breaking out of `else`, when first time you find non-digit character. This will skip any consecutive digit coming after that. So, you should not `break`.
- In fact, you should add `break` out of the loop once you find 13 consecutive digit.
- You're not really looking for consecutive digits, but just total number of non-cosnecutive digits. At least the current logic without `break` would work this way. You should reset the `checkConsecutive` variable to `0` when you find a non-digit character.

So, changing your `for` loop to this will work:

```
for (int i = 0, len = cardNo.length(); i < len; i++)
{
    if (Character.isDigit(cardNo.charAt(i))) {
        checkConsecutive++;

    } else if (checkConsecutive == 13) {
        isConsecutive = true;
        break;

    } else {
        checkConsecutive = 0;
    }
}
```

Of course I don't know what is `starValue` and `maskValue`, so I've removed it. You can add it appropriately.

---

BTW, this problem can also be solved with regex:

```
if (cardNo.matches(".*\\d{13}.*")) {
    System.out.println("13 consecutive digits found");
}
```

Comment: @Sathish Are you always going to mask after the first 6 digits? And also that should always be `%`?

Comment: if 13 Consecutive digits found i need to take all Consecutive digits and mask and concat back to normal for input XXXX123456789123456 result should be XX123456%%%%%3456XX and for input 123456789123456XXXX result should be 123456%%%%%3456XXXX

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static void checkPosCardNoAndMask(String cardNo) {
    int n = 1;
    char c1 = cardNo.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 1, len = cardNo.length(); i < len && n < 13; i++) {
        char c2 = cardNo.charAt(i);
        if (c2 >= '1' && c2 <= '9' && (c2 - c1 == 1 || c2 == '1' && c1 == '9')) {
            n++;
        } else {
            n = 0;
        }
        c1 = c2;
    }
    if (n == 13) {
        System.out.println("Consecutive found!!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Consecutive not found!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: the number will be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void checkPosCardNoAndMask(String cardNo) {
        if (cardNo.matches("[0-9]{13,}")) {
            System.out.println("Consecutive found!!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Consecutive not found!!");
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with your code then make one change

```
public void checkPosCardNoAndMask(String cardNo) {
    String maskNumber = "";
    String starValue = "";
    boolean isConsecutive = false;
    int checkConsecutive = 0;
    for (int i = 0, len = cardNo.length(); i < len; i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(cardNo.charAt(i))) {
            maskNumber = maskNumber + cardNo.charAt(i);
            checkConsecutive++;
        } else {
            if (checkConsecutive >= 13)
                {isConsecutive = true;break;}
            else
                checkConsecutive=0;
            starValue = starValue + cardNo.charAt(i);
        }

    }
    if (isConsecutive) {
        System.out.printIn("Consecutive found!!");
    } else {
        System.out.printIn("Consecutive not found!!");
    }

}
```

Comment: @Sathish can you tell me what is the criteria of your mask function?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to mask card numbers in a string. There is one external dependency in following code http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/ for StringUtils

```
/**
 * Returns safe string for cardNumber, will replace any set of 13-16 digit
 * numbers in the string with safe card number.
 */
public static String getSafeString(String str) {

    Pattern CARDNUMBER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d{13,16}+");
    Matcher matcher = CARDNUMBER_PATTERN.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String cardNumber = matcher.group();
        if (isValidLuhn(cardNumber)) {
            str = StringUtils.replace(str, cardNumber, getSafeCardNumber(cardNumber));
        }
    }
    return str;
}

public static boolean isValidLuhn(String cardNumber) {

    if (cardNumber == null || !cardNumber.matches("\\d+")) {
        return false;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    boolean alternate = false;
    for (int i = cardNumber.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.substring(i, i + 1));
        if (alternate) {
            n *= 2;
            if (n > 9) {
                n = (n % 10) + 1;
            }
        }
        sum += n;
        alternate = !alternate;
    }
    return (sum % 10 == 0);
}

/**
 * Returns safe string for cardNumber, will keep first six and last four
 * digits.
 */ 
public static String getSafeCardNumber(String cardNumber) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cardlen = cardNumber.length();
    if (cardNumber != null) {
        sb.append(cardNumber.substring(0, 6)).append(StringUtils.repeat("%", cardlen - 10)).append(cardNumber.substring(cardlen - 4));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: brief explanation of your code will do better or inline comments.